# What does the "P" stand for in Super Mario's P-Switches?

Tags: mario-series

In pretty much every Super Mario platformer game after Super Mario Bros 3, there is a "P-switch" which turns blocks into coins and vice-versa (and sometimes some other thing, like make special blocks appear). Many people assume it stands for "Power" and some think it might stand for "Paratroopa" because "P-wings" let you fly like a Paratroopa (sort of), but these are all unsourced guesses.

Incredibly, as far as I can tell, the internet simply *does not know* what the P actually stand for!

[image: The trusty P-switch itself]

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a thread somewhere referencing a Nintendo Power comic, where Luigi asked the same question and there ended up being no "official" response.

Comment: Yeah, from what I've been able to surmise there is no "official" meaning, so your guesses are as meaningful as anyone elses.

Comment: I always thought "Pow!" or "Power"